# usage of match (string string) function in java

Tags: java

I have a question:

I'm testing a guitar tab player application in java.

For playing this tabs;

```
String tabstr =
                  "e|-------------------------------|\n"
                + "B|-5-5-6-8-8-6-5-3-1-1-3-5-5-3-3-|\n"
                + "G|-------------------------------|\n"
                + "D|-------------------------------|\n"
                + "A|-------------------------------|\n"
                + "E|-------------------------------|\n";
```

such function is used;

```
public String notesToPlay()
{
    String result = new String();
    boolean firstIteration = true;

    for (String fret: match(tab, "/(\\d+)/g"))
    {
        if (!firstIteration)
            result += " ";
        result += "B" + fret;
        firstIteration = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

An the output of this function is something like this:

```
"B5 B5 B6 B8 B8 B6 B5 B3 B1 B1 B3 B5 B5 B3 B3"
```

If I want to play these tabs;

```
    String tabstr = 
              "e|-7-----7-----7-----7-----5-----3-----3-----2-----0-----0-----|\n"
            + "B|---0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0---|\n"
            + "G|-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-|\n"
            + "D|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n"
            + "A|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n"
            + "E|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
```

and if the output should be like this;

```
"e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e5 B0 G0 e3 B0 G0 e3 B0 G0 e2 B0 G0 e0 B0 G0 e0 B0 G0"
```

how can I modify notesToPlay() method by using match(string string), or is it easy to use another approach?

Could you help me in this issue?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question - It doesn't make that much sense to model this kind of data as a `String`. If the data is in a long string form like that, I would recommend splitting at each note. Like `tabstr.split("\|")`, and then you can traverse from `0 to n-1` of each note's array, assuming they are all the same length.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I think making char array is better. But if you would be able to write the method for me, it would be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIth your tabStr you have three items of data nested at different levels in the string:

1. you have 6 strings to play - each on a new line
2. you have a name for each string (E,A,D,G,B,e)
3. a sequence of fret numbers indicating which fret is played, and when.

You need to identify, and trap each of these events.

There's an assumption here that each string has the same number of 'beats'....

Still, the following should help you figure out your next steps.....

Note, it relies on valid input, it uses 'split' to break each string in to a separate line.

It uses the toCharArray to break each line in to the individual fret fingering.

Your requirements do not indicate what to do with frets > 9... so, that's an exercise for you.

The code stores each fingering in to a new inner class, and then builds that up again to get the output you need.

For me, the output is:

```
e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e7 B0 G0 e5 B0 G0 e3 B0 G0 e3 B0 G0 e2 B0 G0 e0 B0 G0 e0 B0 G0
```

Your results may be different.

```
public class DeTab {

    private static class TabString {
        private final int[] frets;
        private final String name;

        public TabString(String name, int[] frets) {
            super();
            this.frets = frets;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int[] getFrets() {
            return frets;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tabstr = 
                "e|-7-----7-----7-----7-----5-----3-----3-----2-----0-----0-----|\n"
              + "B|---0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0---|\n"
              + "G|-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-|\n"
              + "D|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n"
              + "A|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n"
              + "E|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";

        System.out.println(decode(tabstr));
    }

    private static String decode(String tabstr) {
        String[] splitTab = tabstr.trim().split("\\s*\n\\s*"); // split on new line.
        TabString[] strings = new TabString[splitTab.length];
        int spos = 0;
        int longest = 0;
        for (String tabString : splitTab) {
            tabString = tabString.trim();
            String[] parts = tabString.split("\\|", 3);
            String name = parts[0];
            char[] fingers = parts[1].toCharArray();
            int[] frets = new int[fingers.length];
            int pos = 0;
            for (char c : fingers) {
                if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    frets[pos] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                } else {
                    frets[pos] = -1;
                }
                pos++;
            }
            strings[spos++] = new TabString(name, frets);
            longest = Math.max(longest, frets.length);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < strings.length; s++) {
                int[] fret = strings[s].getFrets();
                if (fret.length >= i && fret[i] >= 0) {
                    sb.append(strings[s].getName()).append(fret[i]).append(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you rolfl, it is a very useful answer :)